# How to adjust hue&saturation settings for laptop display on Ubuntu/Linux?

Tags: display

I can adjust the display settings in Windows 10 via Intel HD Graphics control panel (like hue and saturation) but when I use Ubuntu or any other Linux distro, I want to do the same thing since in default settings my laptop screen shows the colors so washed out.

Is there anything to manage this?

Thank you.

Comment: Not yet from Intel, as per https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-Gfx-Panel-Possible-Future